# How to catch the name of the shared application clicked?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

For statistics usage, I need to know what shared application the user clicked on.
I used:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_with)));
```

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more explanation reg you question

Comment: good question.. but may be you can watch the broadcasts after startActivity... because whatever user selects, android gonna launch that activity through a broadcast/intent... got my point?

Comment: I need to know if the user clicked on Facebook, e-mail, sms, ...